# html parser in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What HTML parsing libraries do you recommend in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638/what-html-parsing-libraries-do-you-recommend-in-java)
>   [Need a good HTML parser on php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873475/need-a-good-html-parser-on-php)
>   [What are the pros and cons of the leading Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)

Hello,
  I have used http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ for parsing html in php and is there is any thing similar to that....

Comment: I think at least 5 relevant questions were shown in "Related questions" for this title.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO,[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is the best HTML Parser

Answer (score 0):

There are a few listed here: http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers However JTidy is very popular among Java developers.

Answer (score 0):

The [Mozilla Java Html Parser](http://mozillaparser.sourceforge.net/) may be of interest to you

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) or Mozilla Java Html Parser

Answer (score 0):

The [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) parser was a real good choice for me because HTML is, depending on it's author, not always well-formed.
Since most parsers expect well-formed xml (or html, for that matter), I needed to use TagSoup in order to be able to parse all html that was fed to my application.